# Matching a plus sign in a grid of characters

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pattern-matching

I was trying to match a pattern in a string using regex. The idea is this.

I have an array of size n*m with G's and non-G's in each entry. I have to find patterns of G in the form of plus sign (+), with all the four arms of plus having same size. For instance, in the example given below:

```
BGBBGB
GGGGGG
BGBBGB
GGGGGG
BGBBGB
BGBBGB

BGB
GGG
BGB
```

is a form of plus sign (+) with each arm of size 1.

I tried to solve the pattern using regex, however, it did not work out for me.

```
match = [(m.start(0), m.end(0)) for m in re.finditer(r'([GG]*G)',l[i])]
```

only matches patterns of same arm length in the horizontal axis, with a G in the center. Not sure how to match pattern of G's with same arm length on all four sides. Will appreciate any answers.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand regular expressions are useful when used on a 1-dimensional array, not on 2-dim array as in your problem.

So I would tend to say that using regular expression might not be a good approach... I tried to match a fixed pattern with a placement of `G` in a `+` pattern, each arm being 1 unit long:

```
B = 0
G = 1

matrix = (
    (B, G, B, B, G, B),
    (G, G, G, G, G, G),
    (B, G, B, B, G, B),
    (B, G, B, B, G, B),
    (G, G, G, G, G, G),
    (B, G, B, B, G, B),
)

pattern = (
    (B, G, B),
    (G, G, G),
    (B, G, B),
)

def getMatrixSize(mat):
    # Return (width, height)
    return (len(mat[0]), len(mat))

def findPattern(mat, pat):
    matches = []

    matsize = getMatrixSize(mat)
    patsize = getMatrixSize(pat)

    for y in range(matsize[1] - patsize[1] + 1):
        for x in range(matsize[0] - patsize[0] + 1):

            submat_cols = mat[y:y+patsize[1]]
            for i in range(patsize[1]):
                submat_row = submat_cols[i][x:x+patsize[0]]
                if submat_row != pat[i]:
                    i = -1
                    break

            if i > 0:
                matches.append((x, y))

    return matches

# Run the thing
print(findPattern(matrix, pattern))
```

My idea was to slide the pattern over the matrix, and compare on each sub-segment of the matrix each segment of the pattern...

Now this is kinda "hard-coded" for a certain pattern.
But you could always go from this and try to allow the pattern to evolve (different arm length)

**Note**: The problem being that with regular expression, you cannot do something like `\w{A}.\w{A}` where `A` would be a shared counter... At least I've never heard of it.

Answer (score 0):

I would choose to use matrix-like method to solve this problem instead of using regex.
In your example, I assume `l` is a list-like including each row of the data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def findPlusSigh(data, pattern):
    # Find indexes which match the pattern
    data = data == pattern
    pattern_index = data.nonzero()
    # List to store result
    result = []
    center_index = []
    # Loop over each matched element
    for i, j in zip(pattern_index[0], pattern_index[1]):
        # Look for arm length from 1 to 100
        for m in range(1, 100):
            try:
                # Break the loop if it's out of range of the data
                if m > i or m > j:
                    break
                # check the matched pattern in 4 directions, i.e., up, left,
                # down, right
                if (all(data[([i-m, i, i+m, i], [j, j-m, j, j+m])])):
                    pass
                else:
                    break
            except:
                break
        # If arm length >= 1
        if m > 1:
            # When the loop breaks, m is 1 more than the actual arm length
            # So we need to minus 1
            # Record the arm length
            result.append(m-1)
            # Record the center index
            center_index.append((i, j))
    return(result, center_index)

# Test data
l = ['BGBBGB', 'GGGGGG', 'BGBBGB', 'GGGGGG', 'BGBBGB', 'BGBBGB']
# The pattern you are matching
pattern = 'G'
# Convert the n by m data into an array where each element is a character
data = np.array([np.array(list(x)) for x in l])
result, center_index = findPlusSigh(data, pattern)
for i, j in zip(result, center_index):
    print ("Data center (Row {}, Column{}) has a plus sign length of {}".format(
        j[0]+1, j[1]+1, i))
```